# Adding Backgroung image to outlook Email Template

Tags: css, html, background-image, newsletter

i am coding html email for outlook where  i have to add background image for whole   , i found  [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3192/add-a-background-image-to-individual-table-cells/)  and did try with it ,  i got the code what i required but problem is that  i am relly unable to get  how to use it , here is what i found from this link

The skinny is that you have to `replace your <html> tag with:<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">`… then add this to your styles in , too`:v:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }As for the <td>` you wish to add the background image to, add the following within the cell (where width and height are the dimensions of the image): 
my `<td>` code is like this

```
<td height="296" colspan="2" valign="top" background="image.png" class="bodyContent" style="border-collapse: collapse">                      

 <div id= "main_content" > content </div>                                               
   </td>
```

how i can relate above mentoined code with this one to add background image , please check link and help me .

Answer (score 0):

**Add a Background Image to a Message in Outlook
To insert an image to the background of an email you are composing in Outlook:**

1. Make sure the message you compose uses HTML formatting.
2. Position the cursor in the message body.
3. Go to the Options tab.
4. Click Page Color.
5. Select Fill Effects... from the menu.
6. Go to the Picture tab.
7. Click Select Picture....
8. Find and highlight the desired background image.
9. Click Insert.
   10.Now click OK.

**Add a Background Image to a Message in Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002 and Outlook 2003
To add a background image to a message in Outlook (provided that you do not use Word for editing emails):**

1. Start composing a new email using HTML formatting.
2. Click in the body of the message.
3. Select Format | Background | Picture... from the menu.
4. Use the file selection dialog to pick an image from your disk.
5. Click OK.

http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_Add_a_Background_Image_to_a_Message_in_Outlook.htm

Comment: i am doing it in Dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

Per the emailbg.net instructions, your code should look like this:

EDIT: Added entire email as test sent to myself, which works as expected in Outlook:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#cccccc" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td background="http://lorempixel.com/400/296/" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" height="296" width="400" colspan="2" valign="top" class="bodyContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:400px;height:296px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/296/" color="#f6f6f6" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>

<div id= "main_content" > content </div>

  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr></table>


</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Just swap out the image to your relative one and change the width to what you need it.

Comment: @JavaStudent Just added to the code so that it included the entire (basic) email. This works perfectly when sent to Outlook.